# Delete the old connectionstring

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

I have created a application that can create connectionstrings and edit connectionstrings.

```
doc.Load(Path.Combine(path, SelectConfigComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "app.config"));
XmlNode xNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "add", "");
XmlAttribute xName = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
XmlAttribute xconnectionString = doc.CreateAttribute("connectionString");
xName.Value = NewKeyTextBox.Text;

xconnectionString.Value = string.Format("data source={0};persist security info={1};initial catalog={2};USER ID={3};password={4}", NewValueTextBox.Text, SecurityInfocomboBox.Text, CatalogcomboBox.Text, UserIDtextBox.Text, PasswordtextBox.Text);

xNode.Attributes.Append(xName);
xNode.Attributes.Append(xconnectionString);
doc.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings")[0].InsertAfter(xNode,
doc.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings")[0].LastChild);

doc.Save(Path.Combine(path, SelectConfigComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "app.config"));
```

With this code I enter a new connectionString. When I want to edit the connectionstring it will add a new one without deleting the other one. How can I delete the old one before adding the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the app.config using "ConfigurationManager" and update the existing values instead of deleting.  Refer following example code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value = "blah";       
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do I have to add this code between the doc.load and doc.save?

Comment: No, try the above example code (without your code), I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have tried your code but It gives me red line under each line with Configuration _The type or namespace name "Configuration" could not be found_

Comment: add this on top of your code: using System.Configuration;, you have to import the library

Comment: I am sure I have added, I have removed it and add it again, but still the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137049/discussion-between-imsome1-and-khaab).

Answer (score 0):

goto web.config file in visual studio and place the code as
below

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=HP_01\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="testEntities" 
       connectionString="metadata=res:///webservice.csdl|res:///webservice.ssdl|res://*/webservice.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HP_01\MSSQLSERVER01;initial catalog=test;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```